# image resize php black background

Tags: php

The problem is the resized image is a black background , i saw there is some issue here but i cant make it ! i tried everything , can you help me  ? thanks Here is my code :

```
header ("Content-type: image/png");

// Traitement de l'image source
$source = imagecreatefrompng(_PS_IMG_DIR_.'test/toasty.png');

$largeur_source = imagesx($source);
$hauteur_source = imagesy($source);

imagealphablending($source, true);
imagesavealpha($source, true);

$nWidth = 400;
$nHeight = 400;

$newImg = imagecreatetruecolor($nWidth, $nHeight);
imagealphablending($newImg, true);
imagesavealpha($newImg,true);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($newImg, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($newImg, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight, $transparent);
imagecopyresampled($newImg, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight,
    $srcWidth, $srcHeight);
$resize = _PS_IMG_DIR_.'test/resize.png';
imagepng($newImg, $resize);
$source = $newImg;

// Traitement de l'image destination
$destination = imagecreatefrompng(_PS_IMG_DIR_.'test/toaster.png');
$largeur_destination = imagesx($destination);
$hauteur_destination = imagesy($destination);

// Calcul des coordonnées pour placer l'image source dans l'image de destination
$destination_x = ($largeur_destination - $largeur_source)/2;
$destination_y =  ($hauteur_destination - $hauteur_source)/2;

// On place l'image source dans l'image de destination
//imagecopymerge($destination, $source, $destination_x, $destination_y, 0, 0, $largeur_source, $hauteur_source, 100);
imagecopy($destination, $source, $destination_x, $destination_y, 0, 0, $largeur_source, $hauteur_source);
 $trost = _PS_IMG_DIR_.'test/trost.png';
// On affiche l'image de destination
imagepng($destination ,$trost );

imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($destination);
```

Comment: What is this code currently doing? What errors are in the log?

Answer (score -1):

This code i used for make thumbnail after image upload. I think it is work for you.

```
function resize($src, $dest, $desired_width='150') {

    /* read the source image */

    $image_mime_types = array(
        'image/jpeg' => 'jpeg',
        'image/png' => 'png',
        'image/bmp' => 'bmp',
    );
    $image_type = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($src));
    $image_type1 = $image_mime_types[$image_type];
    if($image_type1 == 'png'){
        $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($src);
    }
    else if($image_type1 == 'jpeg'){
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    }
    else if($image_type1 == 'bmp'){
        $source_image = imagecreatefromwbmp($src);
    }
    else{
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    }

    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

    /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
    $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
    return imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);
}
$src='D:/server/xampp/htdocs/project/image/test.png'; // Your image path.
$dest='D:/server/xampp/htdocs/project/image/resize/test_thumb.png'; // Your destination image path with an image.
$image_width=200; // Wanted resized image width only.
resize($src,$dest,$image_width);
```